# Recaptcha data-callback function

Tags: c#, recaptcha

I'm trying to wire up a recaptcha callback function but it won't allow me to pass in any parameters into the function.  What I'm looking to do is something like the following:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha"  data-sitekey="#############" data-callback="recaptchaFunction(parameter)"></div>
```

When the recaptcha check is completed it just comes back and says it can't find the function.  The function does exist.  If I take out the parameter from both the div and the function the callback works.  Is there a way to call the function with parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Google reCaptcha V2 allows for parameters in the data-callback. You get the parameters for the callback as hidden form fields or HTML data attributes.

```
<div class="g-recaptcha"  data-sitekey="#############" data-callback="recaptchaFunction"></div>
```

Then for the callback function:

```
var recaptchaFunction = function(){
     var parameter = $('#htmElement').attr( "data-parameter" );
  // or
  // var parameter = $('htmElement').val();
 // rest of your code goes in here.
};
```

hth,
larry

Answer (score 0):

The `data-callback` attribute should just be the callback function's name. The callback function itself is provided with a parameter you can use.

```html
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="..." data-callback="recaptcha_callback" />

<script>
    function recaptcha_callback(parameter) {
        console.log('parameter:', parameter);
    }
</script>
```